# Work on Core Data without persisting changes on another thread

Tags: swift, core-data

I work with Core Data. At some points I need to calculate some data. While I calculate the data I do changes to my data. But I do not want to persist those changes while still be able to read the original data.

So in a function I would need something like this:

```
func doSomething() -> something {
    // Get data with Core Data
    // Set variables on those data to do calculations
    // return a value like X
    // Delete/forget all changes on the data in this function. I will not need it anymore
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Copy the data from Core Data to a struct(s) and work with the struct(s) locally

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: sorry for the question: How do I copy data from an `@ObservedObject` within a view into a struct? All what I tried kept the Binding to the original core data object.

Comment: @JFS Copying data from a class object into a new struct object should be straightforward so I have no idea what makes your case difficult or different and I doubt we can figure this out in the comments section so you better post a proper question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Do your work on a different managed object context, and then never save changes on that context. The `performBackgroundTask(_:)` is a good way to do this. You'd do something like

1. Create a new context using `performBackgroundTask`. Use the closure you pass in for the steps below.
2. Fetch whatever objects you need from that context.
3. Do your calculations and whatever else you need to do.
4. Get your result
5. Don't ever save changes on this new context. Let it get deallocated with unsaved changes.